# Export/Import blob image in sqlite db to xml file

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I have text and image stored in text and blob columns in sqlite database.

Is it possible to export the two columns (text and blob ) into text format in XML file ? how to export/import blob in this situation?

if this is not possible, or there is another or better way for that please lead me how to ease sharing and exchanging data (text and images stored in db)  without building a website or web application as a medium between sender and receiver?

the goal is query the data from database in sender's phone, export it to file, send it by any available way, reload it into new database on receiver's phone.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the blob to base64 ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html ) and the blob's getBytes()